How do I cite a Reddit dialog in APA style?
How do I cite this screenshot in APA format? It's a screenshot of the process of posting. Also what URL would I provide?

Currently, I have:

r/DMAcademy. (n.d.). Screenshot of Flairs and Tags [Screenshot]. reddit.com/r/DMAcademy/submit/?type=TEXT


Does this count as a dialogue? If anything I would think it's the process of setting up the dialogue.

@Michael I think that whether it is a "dialog" or not is rather immaterial; but feel free to edit. My point was to highlight that it's an interactive button-clicky bit, not a webpage you are citing for the information.

That's kind of what I was asking. Do I credit the community, no date, and link to the page that lets you create a post.

I would call this a "dialog box" in UI terms rather than a dialog in interpersonal terms. Are you aware of the different meanings?

Not at all actually @Brian. This is my first time really having to use APA and the past month I've gotten points docked for messing it up.
